# How to Set Call Back For Enter key of GtkTextView?

Tags: python, pygtk

how can I set call back on enter key of GtkTextView Widget and set TextView to work like gtk.entry (single-line)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import gtk

tv = gtk.TextView()

def keyPress(widget, event):
    if gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval) == 'Return':
        ## do something
        return True
    return False

tv.connect('key-press-event', keyPress)

win = gtk.Dialog()
win.vbox.pack_start(tv)
win.vbox.show_all()
win.run()
```

But a question: If don't want multi-line input, so why you are using TextView instead of Entry?!

Comment: You should explain what the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `65293` is.

Comment: I'd suggest using `gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval) == 'Return'` instead of checking the numeric keyval, this is more explanatory to somebody reading the code. Might also be better in case somebody remaps their keyboard for one reason or the other.